# Postgres Query Plan hugely differs for query with increased timetamp range

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

Hey there postgres specialists.
We are facing a strange behavior with one of our tables. While increasing the queried timestamp range there is the tipping point where the query time suddenly increases by about 5 times.

The table we are looking at:

```
                   Table "measurements.hourly_measurement_recordings"
        Column         |              Type              | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 dimension_identifier  | integer                        |           | not null | 
 occasion_identifier   | integer                        |           | not null | 
 items_identifier      | bit(64)                        |           | not null | 
 beginning_of_timeslot | timestamp(0) without time zone |           | not null | 
 dumped_weight         | integer                        |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "hourly_measurement_recordings_kind_identifier_type_identifier_p" UNIQUE, btree (occasion_identifier, dimension_identifier, items_identifier, beginning_of_timeslot)
    "hourly_measurement_recordings_kind_identifier_type_identifier_b" btree (occasion_identifier, dimension_identifier, beginning_of_timeslot)
```

First query + plan:
https://explain.depesz.com/s/LyzL

Second query + plan:
https://explain.depesz.com/s/ZCvZ

The only difference between those 2 queries is the increased timestamp range:

`'2021-03-15 23:00:00Z', '2021-04-19 21:00:00Z'`

vs

`'2021-03-14 23:00:00Z', '2021-04-19 21:00:00Z'`

As you can see there is a shift from a `Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan` to a `Parallel Seq Scan` which increases the query time.

Here I some specs of the used database:

- PostgreSQL v13.1
- Running on AWS db.t3.medium with 2 vCPUs, 4GB of RAM, General Purpose SSD (40GB)

I am not really experienced with database configurations so I don't really know which parameters might be useful for you - just let me know if there is any more information relevant to share.

Thank you,
Nick

Comment: You might want to change work_mem, both queries are using external merge for the sorting. Try something like 100MB: SET work_mem TO '100MB'; and try again.

Comment: I would also try an index like this, starting with the beginning_of_timeslot:     "hourly_measurement_recordings_kind_identifier_type_identifier_c" btree (beginning_of_timeslot , occasion_identifier, dimension_identifier);

Comment: tyvm - I will try both

Comment: One Question:
the query is:
`WHERE beginning_of_timeslot WHERE (dimension_identifier and occasion_identifier) OR ...`

so would the index order be `[beginnig_of_timeslot, dimension_identifier, occasion_identifier]` or `[beginning_of_timeslot, occasion_identifier, dimension_identifier]`

Comment: What column has the most unique values? That one should come first.

Comment: @FrankHeikens again thank you for you help. appreciate it.
Upping the work_mem already helped a great deal - we can now query more data in almost the same time.
dimension/occasion identifiers are fixed - there are more `occasions_identifiers` then `dimension_identifiers` so I will try it that way

Comment: https://explain.depesz.com/s/hVNa I added the index now - it seems like the query still uses the old index

Comment: Most time is spend on the sort: Sort 1 4,340.355 ms 70.6 %. What is your setting for work_mem? And could you increase it to lets say a 100MB ?

Comment: Hey - yes I saw that too now - I worked my way up to work_mem 200MB - then the query plan switched from `merge sort` on disk to `quick sort` in memory but the execution time did not really change. It even got worse sometimes on a scale from 100 to 200ms.

Comment: How is 200ms worse than 6.1 second? And you started at 29 seconds. What is it that I'm missing in this picture?

Comment: Sorry I was talking about the sort step which got about 200ms worse when I upped the work_mem to 200MB and it switched to quick sort.
Yes you are absolutely right - switching to 100MB helped initially reducing the time from about 29 seconds to 6 seconds. But doubling it again did not change anything except for postgres to use quick sort in memory which did not improve the query time:
https://explain.depesz.com/s/Obnj in this run you can see that postgres switched to quick sort

Comment: The comments seem to have gone off on a tangent of how to make the fast query faster, rather than how to make the slow query faster.  The sort is the bottleneck for the fast query, but not nearly so for the slow query.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably going to be a tipping point where the seq scan actually becomes faster than the bitmap scan.  And there will also be a point where the planner *thinks* the seq scan will become faster.  And these will almost never be exactly aligned because the planner will never be perfect.  So, this is not very surprising.

One remarkable thing is that the bitmap scan found every block it needed already in memory.  It is hard to believe that this is a realistic situation.  It probably occurred because you ran the exact same query repeatedly.  What if you query a different set of parameters, so that not all the data is already in memory?

It looks like you are running with more or less default settings for the planner.  But for SSD disks, the default setting of random_page_cost is usually too high.  Changing it to 1.1 rather than 4 is probably more suitable.  This alone is likely to shift the cut-over point in the appropriate direction, although I don't know it will shift it enough.

Your setting of max_parallel_workers_per_gather seems to be at last 2.  But for a t3.medium instance, this should probably be 0 or at most 1.  (Also, you shouldn't use t3 instances in the first place if you care about performance, as their performance is erratic by design).  Also, you seem to be using a burstable IO class.  But once you have exhausted your IO credits, performance falls off a cliff, which seems to have happened here for the seq scan.

Comment: Thank you - I will look into your suggestions.
I added a index for the `beginning_of_timeslot` column (no multicolumn) which changed the query plan again from a `bitmap scan` to a `parallel index scan` which seems to have a good impact: https://explain.depesz.com/s/SFHd

You are absolutely right - I ran the same query multiple times and using a different time range results in a much longer query time but the same query plan is used.
The usage of a t3 instance is currently cost related - the data is rarely queried but sometimes in huge chunks and the insertion of it works just fine with t3.